# Why my dotnetOpenAuth fails using log4net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to debug why I get this error:

> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

on this line:

```
  consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authCallbakUrl, null, null));
```

So I added log4net, but it doesn't work for me.

My web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- Others sections -->
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
  <!-- log4net is a 3rd party (free) logger library that dotnetopenid will use if present but does not require. -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="RelyingParty.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date (GMT%date{%z}) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="TracePageAppender" type="OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms.Code.TracePageAppender, OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date (GMT%date{%z}) [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TracePageAppender" />
    </root>
    <!-- Specify the level for some specific categories -->
    <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
      <level value="ALL" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Tried with and without this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" />
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="4.0.30319" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I configure the log4net instance

```
  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Comment: Try adding <log4net debug="true"> to see if that helps you discern why it is unable to log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding redirect suggests you're using log4net v4.0.30319, which doesn't exist.  The latest version is 1.2.11, and the version DNOA is compiled against is 1.2.10.  Once you fix the binding redirect I suspect it will work.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalApplication.cs:

decorate it
**[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]**

To get a reference to logger from other places ex.:
**ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);**

Comment: Global.ascx? I don't have `GlobalApplication.cs`